# Xpages randomly freezing

Tags: xpages

In developing Xpages applications I have noticed that the applications will intermittently and apparently randomly freeze. It happens when I am changing code and previewing quite a bit in XPiNC, which I might be able to understand. But at times it happens when I am just editing a document.

For example, I just updated a RT field in a document using CKEditor, and the app froze about 12 or 15 times. I will no longer be able to move the cursor or move scroll bars up or down. I am able to switch to a different tab (like my email) but if I try to switch back to the Xpages app, I will still see the email application.

I have checked the "IBM Technical Support" Folder for the Xpages log and the console log, with nothing there, and I have checked the Help ==> Support Trace and Log, nothing there either.

We are running Revision 20131022.1138 (Release 9.0.1) on the server, and I am running the same on my client and designer.

Comment: Does it happen when you run the xpage on the server or just when you run the app locally?

Comment: I am running the app on the server; I have not tried running it locally. But I want to make sure, Patrick, you are not talking about checking the "Run App On Server" property Xpages Properties are you?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the "run app on server" property. I think testing that option will give you some more information.

Comment: I will do so. But I am not sure what more information it will give me? Do you mean information in logs?

Comment: I am thinking information for troubleshooting. Lets say that you put the nsf on the server and it experiences the same issues, and then you run the app on the server and it also runs fine. You will know that its xpinc causing the problem.

Comment: OK that is good. I made that change and then tried to open the app in XPiNC and it is asking me to log in. Why? That makes no sense. And it won't let me log in anyway.

Comment: Is the nsf on the server or local? If its local I think you need to allow anonymous access.

Comment: No it is on the server. I closed my client and designer, reopened, then removed the app from the workspace, and open from an Open Dialogue box and I am still challenged for authentication, and it still fails when I try to authenticate.

Comment: Do you have SSO enabled on that server?

Comment: My admin said we do. I do believe I have tried this setting before on a different db and it opened just fine. Very weird.    Isn't there a whole series of things you have to do to make this work on the server?

Comment: Change the ACL to allow anonymous access and it should work. Or since notes uses FF, type about:config and modify this key network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris and put in your domain name.

Comment: My two cents: look closely at the client - what happens when it freezes? What about taking NSD during freeze time and analyze it?. Clock debug is another option, too

Comment: What is clock debug?